# Building Graph-QL for Microsoft Azure // "import okhttp3.Request" not importing

Tags: java, azure, graphql

Trying to follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java?tabs=aad&tutorial-step=3 to build connectivity to Microsoft Azure AD.
I have taken directly from the sample, so far I'm able to import everything except the `import okhttp3.Request` jar? See screenshots showing I have dependency but not able to use. This is needed for the GraphServiceClient type?

Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the update intellij from 2019.x.x to 2022.3.2 community version. The IDE comes with a kotlin plugin that fixes the issue.